# Question about choosing a certain number of people from a set to form two groups.

Tags: combinatorics

If I had a group of $10$ people and I had to make two groups, one of size $6$ and one of size $4$ then clearly the number of ways in which to do this is $10\choose4$ $=$ $10\choose6$ ways.

Yet if I was to alter the question and say I want both groups to be of size $5$ then the answer is then there are $\frac{1}{2}$ $\times$ $10\choose5$. I really can't see why this is the case could anyone explain.

Nevermind I got it. Because if we order the people one to ten then clearly choosing $1,2,3,4,5$ is the same as choosing $6,7,8,9,10$ so the method counts double. Clearly this is not the case for the other example.

Answer (score 1):

In the $6:4$ case each of the two groups a priori has a distinguishing feature. When the two groups will be assigned different tasks (say, digging and weeding) there is no factor ${1\over2}$ in the $5:5$ case either.